# How do I print the full value of a long string in dbx?

Tags: c, string, debugging, aix, dbx

I  want to print the full length of a C-string in dbx. How do I force dbx to print the whole string?

```
if its a long string it gives following msg:
(dbx) p svalue
expression too large to evaluate
(dbx)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, it says

> `-e num` Chooses a large size for the evaluation stack (as large as you want). The default stack size is 20,000 bytes. num = number of bytes. If you see the message too large to evaluate, rerun dbx suppling a value greater than 20,000

Comment: But, the OP should really consider whether they want to look through >20,000 characters of output -- there's got to be a better way...

Comment: @JohnHascall he said that he wanted to force it to print the C-string and that's how he can do it, now if he should do other things, it all depends oon the form of the OP question.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing your answer, it's the right answer to the question asked.